# Cannot get DOT NET CORE MVC to return multiple LINQ results to a view

Tags: javascript

I am able to pass one value from the controller method, see first cal query to return just the calorie value from the SQL LINQ query. However, I cannot get two colums, see my code controller code and javascript in the view below (I cannot work out what is causing zero data to be populated

I can see var mytext in javascript code return : {"foodCal":101,"foodVarient":"Vegan"}

```
public JsonResult GetCalories(string Productdata)
{
            //THis is the orginal code which returns one value, CALORIES
            //var calquery = (from c in _context.Foods
            //                where c.FoodName == Productdata
            //                select c.FoodCal).FirstOrDefault();

           
            var calquery = (from c in _context.Foods
                            where c.FoodName == Productdata
                            select new
                            { c.FoodCal, c.FoodVarient }
                            ).FirstOrDefault();

            if (calquery != null)
            {
                return Json(calquery); 
            }
            else
            {
                calquery = null;
                return Json(calquery);
            }
}

    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ()
    {
                    document.getElementById("FoodType").onchange = function ()
                {
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetCalories")',
                            data: { Productdata: document.getElementById("FoodType").value },
                            
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                var mytext = JSON.stringify(data);
                                alert(mytext);
                                var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                                document.getElementById("FoodCalories").value = obj.foodCal;
                                document.getElementById("FoodHealth").value = obj.foodVarient;
    
                            }
                    });
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem

var object =JSON.parse(**mytext**), not json

problem solved.

Hope other people benefit from this code.